# How to compromise between using a lagged dependent variable and observation loss

Tags: panel-data, sample-size, lags

I am working with panel data of several thousand observations in five time periods. As I have a strong reason to believe that past values of the dependent variable (DV) affect subsequent values of the DV, I decided to include the lagged dependent variable (lag of 1) in the model. However, when I include the lagged DV in the model, the number of observations in the model dramatically falls to 7,355 from 9,367 (a reduction of more than 2,000 observations).

Should I use the lagged DV in the model and lose 2000 observations (about 20% of the total observations) or should I ignore the lagged DV at the expense of the resulting bias?